# Android Recyclerview scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am new to Android development. I am using recycler view for showing a list. I assume it has default behavior of scrolling, but it's not happening. Can anyone give me some suggestion. Following is the layout that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.team.sidhesh.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sliderTempImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_image_height"
            android:src="@drawable/homescreen_logo"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Sometime this happens due to the drawables you are using in your imageview.  The drawables should not be much large

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.team.sidhesh.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sliderTempImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_image_height"
            android:src="@drawable/homescreen_logo"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="470dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also make sure you add the dependencies in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `RecyclerView` in the `AppBarLayout`? Shouldn't it be under the `CoordinatorLayout` and outside of the `AppBarLayout`?

To achieve what you expect, Check this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Which shows/says: `<!-- Your scrolling content -->`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <!-- Your scrolling content -->

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So you'll need to put `RecyclerView` outside of the `AppBarLayout` and then add: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to the `RecyclerView`. I've set `AppBarLayout` `layout_height` to `wrap_content` either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.team.sidhesh.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sliderTempImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_image_height"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/homescreen_logo" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And what was that `ImageView` all about? For using Slider? Then perhaps you'll need to put it all together with a [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) too!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is wrap the recyclerView into either [Scrollview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) or [HorizontalscrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Comment: Can you add more info to the links you added?